# Inverted Circle?

Tags: circles, exponential-function

The equation I have is

$$\Large x^{\frac23} + y^{\frac23} = 3^{\frac23} $$

I know what the graph looks like, but I don't know how I would find points other than the intercepts mathematically. How would I do that?

Comment: I personally don't understand what it is you're asking - please clarify.

Comment: If vyou are curious about the $y$'s that correxpond to a particular value of $x$, such as $x=0.4$, plug in and solve for $y$. You might be interested also in a question like when is $y=x$, i.e. where does the curve meet the line $y=x$. One can calculate, just put $y=x$ and solve.

Comment: I think Kekker's problem lies in the understanding of [fractional exponents.](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/exponent5.htm)

Comment: This is an [astroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid), a special case of a [superellipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse).

Comment: I understand what fractional exponents are, and I know the shape of the graph. I just don't understand how to undo a fractional exponent in this equation so as to get an answer.

For example, I plug in 1 for x, so I can find the y coordinate for x=1 for my graph.
$$\Large 1^{\frac23} + y^{\frac23} = 3^{\frac23} $$

That I can simplify to
$$\Large 1 + y^{\frac23} = 3^{\frac23} $$

How would I simplify that further?

Answer (score 4):

Try $\begin{cases}
x=3\cos^3\theta\\
y=3\sin^3\theta\\
\end{cases}$     or, for rational solutions, $\begin{cases}
x=3\left({{2t}\over{t^2+1}}\right)^3\\
y=3\left({{t^2-1}\over{t^2+1}}\right)^3\\
\end{cases}$

Comment: Perhaps this would lead to a rational parametrization of the curve, using the Weierstrass substitution. (+1)

Comment: I like your second formulation because it allows quick and easy hand computation of loads of rational points.